Garbage collection instruction in i386 – which one and why?
In the paper "Symbolics, Inc.: A failure of heterogeneous engineering"  by Alvin Graylin, Kari Anne, Hoier Kjolaas, Jonathan Loflin and Jimmie D. Walker III, there's a mention that:

Symbolics at one time was working with Intel to build a development platform based on the 386, which led to the inclusion of an extra instruction in the final 386 architecture to facilitate garbage collection

Which instruction is it?  How can it used specifically to facilitate garbage collection?

Related and possibly useful: David Moon's paper on the GC design Purely a guess, but the only new instructions of the 386 that look relevant to me would be BTS/BTR/BTC--Bit test and (set|reset|complement).

@JerryCoffin: A "clear byte, with lazy caching semantics" instruction would seem useful in a GC system, since executing such an instruction on a byte within an object header every time a reference to it is stored someplace new could be done much more cheaply than a store with normal semantics.  Any pending stores to such bytes would need to be resovled before any GC pass, but there would otherwise be no need for a core to notify other cores about such stores.

BTS/BTR/BTC do look useful for manipulating and acting on a mark bit while doing mark and sweep GC.

The paper you linked to starts with this sentence: "Thomas F. Knight, Jack Holloway and Richard Greenblatt developed the first LISP at the MIT
Artificial Intelligence Laboratory in the late 1970s". After that, I'm not sure I'm going to believe anything else in there.

The paper has some obvious typos throughout. The particular one here is the omission of "machine" (or "Machine") after the word LISP.

@supercat: Oh, there are lots of things that could be useful--but I'm restricting the search to the new instructions added in the 386.

If it is just a missing word, their editing was so careless that four people didn't catch that meaning-changing omission in the very first sentence of their paper. Which doesn't really inspire confidence, either.

The paper generally has poor editing.  Did you know the PDP-10 with an 18-bit address can only address two-to-the-18 bits of memory?  Which is also 256 kilobytes, apparently.

Curiously, the paper references Inventing Accuracy. This is a very interesting book that every nerd should read. It shows how we end up in sometimes rediculous technological situations for "just 'cuz" and "but they are doing it!".

TY, @MauryMarkowitz, for the recommendation.  That author's Mechanizing Proof also looks interesting.

@JerryCoffin: I'm not sure to what extent the described instructions facilitate GC more than any other kind of task.  I think the x86 has an instruction which clears memory at an effective address, and the fact that the instruction unconditionally stores zero could be exploited by cache controllers that chose to exploit that.

@supercat: I don't know that they do--but they look like they would be useful for GC. Most of the instructions added as of the 386 look completely irrelevant to GC.

@supercat: The 80386 didn't have a data cache at all.

@NateEldredge: The CPU itself didn't, but I'm sure Intel was aware that future systems would do so.
